# has no method getColumnModel EXTJS4

Tags: extjs4

I am new to EXTJS. I am working on migrating the existing extjs3 code to extjs4.

How can I replace the code in order to work in extjs4?

```
var cm = this.grid.getColumnModel();
```

cm is being used as below:

```
cm.getColumnCount();

var c = cm.getColumnAt(i);
```

Thanks in advance!

Rahul

Comment: I'm still stuck here. Can anyone help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var columns = this.grid.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();
```

That will return an array of all the columns in the grid. You can then replicate the actions you listed above:

```
// replaces cm.getColumnCount();
columns.length;

// replaces var c = cm.getColumnAt(i);
var c = columns[i];
```

Comment: ed = c.getEditor(); 
    ed.setWidth(c.getWidth()); 
How to replace these 2 functions?

Comment: `Ext.grid.column.Column` already has a function `getEditor()`. And the editor field should already size itself appropriately.